# API de Notificações do PayPal: Reconhecimento de Variáveis

Tags: php

Utilizando a `API` de notificações do `Paypal` através do Simulador `IPN` encontrado em https://developer.paypal.com/developer/ipnSimulator/, obtive o seguinte retorno que é o padrão do simulador:

Minhas dúvidas são:

Na lista abaixo,

A) Quem é o `número do pedido` na `base de dados da minha loja` que enviei ao `Paypal` ainda na fase de `checkout`? Seria o `receiver_id`?

B) Qual é o `valor total do pedido` que compreende o `somatório` de `todos os itens do pedido`? Seria o `mc_gross`?

C) Na minha loja, eu `somo os fretes de todos os produtos` e envio ao `Paypal` apenas o `somatório`, então o `frete` aqui é referenciado com `mc_shipping`?

Grato a quem puder ajudar?

```
array (
  'payment_type' => 'instant',
  'payment_date' => 'Sat Oct 15 2016 09:34:52 GMT-0300 (Hora oficial do Brasil)',
  'payment_status' => 'Completed',
  'address_status' => 'confirmed',
  'payer_status' => 'verified',
  'first_name' => 'John',
  'last_name' => 'Smith',
  'payer_email' => 'buyer@paypalsandbox.com',
  'payer_id' => 'TESTBUYERID01',
  'address_name' => 'John Smith',
  'address_country' => 'United States',
  'address_country_code' => 'US',
  'address_zip' => '95131',
  'address_state' => 'CA',
  'address_city' => 'San Jose',
  'address_street' => '123 any street',
  'business' => 'seller@paypalsandbox.com',
  'receiver_email' => 'seller@paypalsandbox.com',
  'receiver_id' => 'seller@paypalsandbox.com',
  'residence_country' => 'US',
  'item_name1' => 'something',
  'item_number1' => 'AK-1234',
  'tax' => '2.02',
  'mc_currency' => 'USD',
  'mc_fee' => '0.44',
  'mc_gross' => '12.34',
  'mc_gross_1' => '12.34',
  'mc_handling' => '2.06',
  'mc_handling1' => '1.67',
  'mc_shipping' => '3.02',
  'mc_shipping1' => '1.02',
  'txn_type' => 'cart',
  'txn_id' => '751042518',
  'notify_version' => '2.1',
  'custom' => 'xyz123',
  'invoice' => 'abc1234',
  'test_ipn' => '1',
  'verify_sign' => 'AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31AgAbMLie9sImKsLNhPgU-vSMC4Iy',
)
```